# Why doesn't the 29th century Starfleet intervene when Janeway travels back in time at the end of Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-voyager, timeline

Over all seven seasons of Voyager, the Starfleet of the 29th century intervened whenever anything was in the wrong time. But why don't they do this when Janeway travels back in time at the end of Voyager in order to change the whole future?